# Running python cron script as non-root user

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I have a small problem running a python script as a specific user account in my CentOS 6 box.

My cron.d/cronfile looks like this:

`5 17 * * * reports /usr/local/bin/report.py > /var/log/report.log 2>&1`

The account `reports` exists and all the files that are to be accessed by that script are `chowned` and `chgrped` to `reports`. The python script is `chmod a+r`. The python script starts with a `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

But this is not the problem. The problem is that I see nothing in the logfile. The python script doesn't even start to run! Any ideas why this might be?

If I change the user to `root` instead of `reports` in the cronfile, it runs fine. However I cannot run it as `root` in production servers.

If you have any questions please ask :)

/e:
If I do `sudo -u reports python report.py` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs run with the permissions of the user that the cron job was setup under.
I.E. Whatever is in the cron table of the `reports` user, will be run as the `reports` user.

If you're having to so `sudo` to get the script to run when logged in as `reports`, then the script likely won't run as a cron job either. Can you run this script when logged in as `reports` without `sudo`?  If not, then the cron job can't either.  Make sense?

Check your logs - are you getting permissions errors?

There are a myriad of reasons why your script would need certain privs, but an easy way to fix this is to set the cron job up under `root` instead of `reports`. The longer way is to see what exactly is requiring elevated permissions and fix that.  Is it file permissions? A protected command? Maybe adding `reports` to certain groups would allow you to run it under `reports` instead of `root`.

*be ULTRA careful if/when you setup cron jobs as root

Comment: Whenever I try to `su - reports` I get a "reports account is not currently available" or something along those lines.

I will check at work tomorrow and post again :)

Comment: I can do `su - reports` now and run the script fine. So the problem is not permissions. I still see no output to the log file.